# Post or update a document to a facebook group via graph api

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I try to post/edit a document to a facebook group with out success. Like described here: [Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912775/facebook-group-docs-api)

I use the following code to post the document:

```
var doc = {
    subject: 'My subject',
    message: 'My Message'
};

FB.api(groupId + '/docs', 'post', doc, function (response) {
    if (response && !response.error) {
        alert('success');
    } else {
        alert('failed');
    }
});
```

Error result:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#3) Unknown method",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 3
  }
}
```

Could anyone guide me in the right direction. Or is this feature not/no longer available via the graph API

Comment: did you do your oauth first.

Comment: Have you requested the `publish_stream` and `manage_groups` permissions?

Comment: Yes the app is authenticated and I have tried with publish_stream and manage_groups in the login button

Comment: It looks like 'manage_groups' doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to my own question:
It looky like it is not possible now. FB update theirs [Graph API Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/groupdoc) and it is not possible to publish, delete and update a group document.